# The following types on /data/ must be associated with the "core_data_file_type" attribute: netmgrd_data_file

Tags: android-kernel

```
[ 33% 5152/15457] build /rom/tb8504/out/target/product/TB8504/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests
FAILED: /rom/tb8504/out/target/product/TB8504/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests 
/bin/bash -c "(/rom/tb8504/out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy_tests -l /rom/tb8504/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.so         -f /rom/tb8504/out/target/product/TB8504/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts  -f /rom/tb8504/out/target/product/TB8504/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts  -p /rom/tb8504/out/target/product/TB8504/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy ) && (touch /rom/tb8504/out/target/product/TB8504/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests )"
The following types on /data/ must be associated with the "core_data_file_type" attribute: netmgrd_data_file

[ 33% 5169/15457] //external/llvm:libLLVM_android link libLLVM_android.so
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
10:30:10 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Device tree: https://github.com/dazza5000/android_device_lenovo_TB8504

Vendor tree:= https://github.com/dazza5000/android_vendor_lenovo_TB8504

Kernel Source:= https://github.com/dazza5000/android_kernel_lenovo_TB8504

ROM Source:= https://github.com/LineageOS/android

Haste or Dogbin URL:= https://del.dog/cemofukino.txt

I manually updated the file here https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_qcom_sepolicy/blob/lineage-16.0/vendor/common/file.te#L46 to include core_data_file_type , but that doesn't feel like a legit fix and won't stick - it also doesn't help me determine the root cause

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Just the fix I mentioned in the last line.